# Pandas - plot Bureau of Labor statistics with years on y-axis and months on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization

I'm working with BLS inflation statistics, which are presented thus:

[image]

I want to make a very simple line chart (probably will use `altair` but that's not entirely relevant to the question).

In pandas, what is the most efficient/idiomatic way to restructure the DataFrame to prepare for time-series visualization in this case?

NOTE: this is essentially the inverse of this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211424/how-to-make-a-years-on-y-axis-and-months-on-x-axis-plot-with-pandas](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/48211424/how-to-make-a-years-on-y-axis-and-months-on-x-axis-plot-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way to do this, but you can loop through all of the month columns, and combine that with all of the values in the year column to a get a `year-month`, and store the values and the year-months together in a `pd.Series`.

For example, we can create a similar dataframe to yours:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## recreate a dataframe with a similar structure
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(4, 13))

month_cols = [datetime.strptime(str(i), "%m").strftime("%b") for i in range(1,13)]
years = [1960.0,1961.0,1962.0,1963.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns= ['Date'] + month_cols
)
df['Date'] = years
```

---

```
>>> df
     Date  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0  1960.0    4    8    5    7    3    7    8    5    4    8    8    3
1  1961.0    5    2    8    6    2    5    1    6    9    1    3    7
2  1962.0    9    3    5    3    7    5    9    7    2    4    9    2
3  1963.0    5    2    4    7    8    3    1    4    2    8    4    2
```

And transform it into a timeseries:

```
ts_index, ts_values = [], []
for col in month_cols:
    ts_values.extend(df[col].tolist())
    ts_index.extend(pd.to_datetime(
        [f"{int(year)}-{col}" for year in years]
    ))
timeseries = pd.Series(
    index=ts_index,
    data=ts_values
).sort_index()
```

---

```
1960-01-01    4
1960-02-01    8
1960-03-01    5
1960-04-01    7
...
1963-09-01    2
1963-10-01    8
1963-11-01    4
1963-12-01    2
```

Answer (score 0):

With a table like this, which I call `bls_df`:

```
    Year      Jan      Feb      Mar  ...      Nov      Dec    HALF1    HALF2
0   2013  230.280  232.166  232.773  ...  233.069  233.049  232.366  233.548
1   2014  233.916  234.781  236.293  ...  236.151  234.812  236.384  237.088
2   2015  233.707  234.722  236.119  ...  237.336  236.525  236.265  237.769
3   2016  236.916  237.111  238.132  ...  241.353  241.432  238.778  241.237
4   2017  242.839  243.603  243.801  ...  246.669  246.524  244.076  246.163
5   2018  247.867  248.991  249.554  ...  252.038  251.233  250.089  252.125
6   2019  251.712  252.776  254.202  ...  257.208  256.974  254.412  256.903
7   2020  257.971  258.678  258.115  ...  260.229  260.474  257.557  260.065
8   2021  261.582  263.014  264.877  ...  277.948  278.802  266.236  275.703
9   2022  281.148  283.716  287.504  ...  297.711  296.797  288.347  296.963
10  2023  299.170      NaN      NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN

[11 rows x 15 columns]
```

Reshape by setting index then unstacking.

```
nbls = bls_df.set_index('Year').unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'month'})
nbls = nbls[nbls['month'].isin(list(calendar.month_abbr))]  # subset to real months
```

Generate date by concatenating the month and year columns in a parseable format:

```
>>> nbls['date'] = pd.to_datetime(nbls['month'] + '-' + nbls['Year'].astype(str))
>>> nbls.sort_values('date')  # nb does not act in-place
    month  Year        0       date
0     Jan  2013  230.280 2013-01-01
11    Feb  2013  232.166 2013-02-01
22    Mar  2013  232.773 2013-03-01
33    Apr  2013  232.531 2013-04-01
44    May  2013  232.945 2013-05-01
..    ...   ...      ...        ...
87    Aug  2023      NaN 2023-08-01
98    Sep  2023      NaN 2023-09-01
109   Oct  2023      NaN 2023-10-01
120   Nov  2023      NaN 2023-11-01
131   Dec  2023      NaN 2023-12-01

[132 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

I also do hope that you know that the BLS already has the data stored in a long format. You can read it in directly using `pd.read_csv(THE_URL, sep='\s+')`, where `THE_URL` is this link: https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.data.0.Current. You will still need to do some working to generate a `datetime` column and also to filter based on the series codes that the BLS assigns, but it isn't too difficult.